# Manipulate HTML element using Javascript function inside angular5 component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I am developing an application which needs to show subscribe newsletter modal on document load. The modal should be loaded after a certain time once the document is fully loaded and needs to be shown only once. So to achieve this, I have implemented this in Javascript using a cookie. But now I want to transfer it to the angular application. Can anybody suggest me, How to show the model using the javascript function inside angular?

My js file is index.js

```
function setCookie(isNewsLetterAlreadyBoxShown, expiryDate){
  var date = new Date();
  date.setDate( date.getTime() + (expiryDate * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  var expires = "expires="+ date.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = "returningUser =" + isNewsLetterAlreadyBoxShown + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cookieName){
  var name = cookieName + "=";
  var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");

  for(var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++){
    var cookie = cookies[i];

    while (cookie.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      cookie = cookie.substring(1);
    }
    if (cookie.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      //                        return cookie.substring(name.length, c.length);
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function checkCookie() {
  var returningUser = getCookie("returningUser");
  if(returningUser){
    return;
  } else {
    showSubscribeNewsLetter();
    setCookie(true, 365);
  }
};

function showSubscribeNewsLetter() {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
      $("#myModal").modal('show');
    }, 2000);
  });
}
```

And component.ts is as follows

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var checkCookie: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-subscribe-newsletter',
  templateUrl: './subscribe-newsletter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./subscribe-newsletter.component.css']
})
export class SubscribeNewsletterComponent implements OnInit {



  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.showSubscribeNewsLetter();
  }

  showSubscribeNewsLetter()
{
  ***new checkCookie();***

}

}
```

My function is running but I am getting $ is not defined error. I know I am accessing the id from another file so I am getting this error. Any way to resolve this issue?

Thank you in advance.

** is the function which is giving error.

Comment: add this  declare const $: any; after import statement

Comment: not working. Same error.

Comment: $ comes from jQuery. Did you import it somewhere in your app?

Comment: did you add above the @component

Comment: @VithuBati yes I did above Component

Comment: @MateuszWitkowski $ here is from javascript function to manipulate my modal.

Comment: @Bikram No, it's not. This line for example is definitely using jQuery library: `$("#myModal").modal('show'); `

Comment: @MateuszWitkowski I have "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js", in application_Cli file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add **jQuery** to your project.

Add jQuery to your **index.html** using CDN
or
install it locally using npm and add it to **angular-cli.json**

Note: Don't forget to restart your server after updating angular-cli.json

Comment: I have "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
        "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"  in angular_cli file

Comment: have you restarted your server after adding jQuery to angular-cli.json?

Comment: Yes. I have added above line for bootstrap. And bootstrap is running well.

Comment: try adding "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js" instead of "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" and restart ur server if this doesn't work then try adding jquery CDN to your index.html

Comment: Using CDN in html file solved the problem. WHy is the problem with Agnular_CLI? I need to remove all the imports from cli and include in index.html file.